# What does the deployment error "Picklist sharing is not supported" mean?

Tags: deployment, error

I'm attempting to deploy a custom field from one org to another and am encountering the error "Picklist sharing is not supported". How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6):

This error seems to arise when you are attempting to deploy a field whose type has changed from a picklist to some other field. For example, if that field exists as a picklist in the target org, but as a checkbox in the source org this error can arise.
The workaround is to first delete this field from the target org.